# how to solve a JNI error has occured in cmd line using edu.mit.jwi

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cmd, jwi

When i run my maven project from eclipse it runs ok. But when i run it from cmd line as a jar file i have the following error:

```
A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again  
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/mit/jwi/IDictionary  
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.mit.jwi.IDictionary
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

But i don't use the
    IDictionary.class 
in my project, instead i use the 
    Dictionary.class 
of jwi library, so i don't understand why i have the above error and what exactly is that.

Please help!!!!

Comment: The class you used, `Dictionary`, implements the interface `IDictionary`. You'll need to have both those in your classpath when your run from the command line.

Comment: "when i run it from cmd line as a jar file i have the following error:" Did you create a fat (executable) JAR?